# Getting Unexpected end of SQL command error , please suggest?

Tags: sql, plsql, compiler-errors

In the code below I am getting "unexpected end of SQL command" error at last line after 't', please help me how to solve it.

```
(SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(j,'DD-Mon-YYYY'),'NIL')
 FROM
   (SELECT *
    FROM abc A
    WHERE A.j =
        (SELECT MAX(VALUE_DATE)
         FROM abc
         WHERE k = A.k
           AND j <=
             (SELECT TODAY
              FROM DATES
              WHERE B ='S'))
      AND k IN (:t))
WHERE k =A.l)EFF_DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, query you posted seems to be incomplete. What is that leading open bracket doing here?

With CTEs (to make the query run), it looks OK:

```
SQL> var t number
SQL> exec :t := 1;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> WITH abc
  2       AS (SELECT SYSDATE j,
  3                  SYSDATE value_date,
  4                  1 k,
  5                  SYSDATE today,
  6                  'S' b
  7             FROM DUAL),
  8       dates AS (SELECT SYSDATE today, 'S' b FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT NVL (TO_CHAR (j, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'NIL')
 10    FROM (SELECT *
 11            FROM abc a
 12           WHERE     a.j = (SELECT MAX (value_date)
 13                              FROM abc
 14                             WHERE     k = a.k
 15                                   AND j <= (SELECT today
 16                                               FROM dates
 17                                              WHERE b = 'S'))
 18                 AND k IN ( :t));

NVL(TO_CHAR
-----------
19-Aug-2020

SQL>
```

It would help if you posted something like that - copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session so that we'd see what **exactly** you did and why Oracle responded as it did.

---

After you added another condition, it seems that the whole query you posted is, actually, source for the `EFF_DATE` column. If that's so (once again: you posted incomplete code; it is difficult to guess what you're doing), then you can't use it that way because `A` table is out of scope at that place:

```
SQL> WITH abc
  2       AS (SELECT SYSDATE j,
  3                  SYSDATE value_date,
  4                  1 k,
  5                  SYSDATE today,
  6                  'S' b,
  7                  1 l
  8             FROM DUAL),
  9       dates AS (SELECT SYSDATE today, 'S' b FROM DUAL)
 10  SELECT (SELECT NVL (TO_CHAR (j, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'NIL')
 11            FROM (SELECT *
 12                    FROM abc A
 13                   WHERE     A.j = (SELECT MAX (VALUE_DATE)
 14                                      FROM abc
 15                                     WHERE     k = A.k
 16                                           AND j <= (SELECT TODAY
 17                                                       FROM DATES
 18                                                      WHERE B = 'S'))
 19                         AND k IN ( :t))
 20           WHERE k = A.l)
 21            EFF_DATE
 22    FROM DUAL;
         WHERE k = A.l)
                   *
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-00904: "A"."L": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

It works, though, if rewritten to

```
 <snip>
 10  SELECT (SELECT NVL (TO_CHAR (j, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'NIL')
 11            FROM (SELECT *
 12                    FROM abc A
 13                   WHERE     A.j = (SELECT MAX (VALUE_DATE)
 14                                      FROM abc
 15                                     WHERE     k = A.k
 16                                           AND j <= (SELECT TODAY
 17                                                       FROM DATES
 18                                                      WHERE B = 'S'))
 19                         AND k IN ( :t)
 20                         AND k = A.l))        --> this
 21            EFF_DATE
 22    FROM DUAL;

EFF_DATE
-----------
19-Aug-2020

SQL>
```

See if it helps. If not, please, post a proper test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data), as well as desired output and rules which lead from *input* to *output*.

Comment: i have added the extra where clause i missed by editing , kindly answer where is the error

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.